# Issues of getting indexes information - SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

Trying to get table indexes information in `SQL Server 2012` I identified a strange situation for one scenarion.

I have a table that contains two indexes referenced to some fields: **Field_1** and **Field_3** mapped over int, null columns (the number means the existing field order into the table designed few years ago...).

I am trying to get information about these indexes like this:

```
nRetCode = ::SQLStatistics(hstmtAux, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, (TCHAR*)(LPCTSTR)strTempTable, SQL_NTS, SQL_INDEX_ALL, SQL_ENSURE);
if (nRetCode == SQL_SUCCESS || nRetCode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
{
    nRetCode = ::SQLBindCol(hstmtAux, 4, SQL_C_SHORT, &swNonUnique, sizeof(SWORD), &cbNonUnique);
    nRetCode = ::SQLBindCol(hstmtAux, 5, SQL_CHAR,    szIdxQualif, sizeof(CHAR) * 130, &cbIdxQualif);
    nRetCode = ::SQLBindCol(hstmtAux, 6, SQL_C_CHAR,  szIdxName, sizeof(CHAR) * 130, &cbIdxName);          
    nRetCode = ::SQLBindCol(hstmtAux, 7, SQL_C_SHORT, &swType, sizeof(SWORD), &cbType);
    nRetCode = ::SQLBindCol(hstmtAux, 8, SQL_C_SHORT, &swSeqInIdx, sizeof(SWORD), &cbSeqInIdx);
    nRetCode = ::SQLBindCol(hstmtAux, 9, SQL_C_CHAR,  szIdxColName, sizeof(CHAR) * 130, &cbIdxColName);

    while (bNoFetch || (nRetCode = ::SQLExtendedFetch(hstmtAux, SQL_FETCH_NEXT, 1, &crow, &rgfRowStatus)) == SQL_SUCCESS || nRetCode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
       if (cbIdxName != SQL_NULL_DATA && _tcslen((TCHAR)szIdxName) > 0) 
       {
           // rest of the code
       }
     // the rest of the code
```

Because **SQLExtendedFetch()** is deprecated I used **SQLFetchScroll()** but the behavior is the same from my interest point of view.

Usually, I get the right information about indexes but in one situation I encounte a strange behavior. It's about having a clustered index into a scenario.

When **Field_1** is Non-Unique, Non-Clustered and **Field_3** is Clusted index I get the right information.

But if the index **Field_1** is Clustered and the **Field_3** is Non-Unique, Non-Clustered I get no information about Field_1 index (eg. szIdxName and szIdxColName are "" and their length is -1 that means `SQL_NULL_DATA`). 
So, I have no Index information. Within while loop, with the next iteration I get correct information about the second index **Field_3**.

I'm not sure whether the problem is with SQLStatistics, the bindings or `SQLFetchScroll` (they all always return `SQL_SUCCESS`). It looks like a problem with the driver when the first index is clustered.

Any ideas for fixing this problem or alternative ways for retrieving indexes information?

Answer (score 0):

There are cases documented for [`SQLStatistics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to return NULL for the 'index' name or 'column name':

> - `COLUMN_NAME`: Column name. If the column is based on an expression, such as SALARY + BENEFITS, the expression is returned; if the expression cannot be determined, an empty string is returned. **NULL is returned if TYPE is SQL_TABLE_STAT**.
> - `INDEX_NAME`: Index name; **NULL is returned if TYPE is SQL_TABLE_STAT**.

Are you sure you do not capture an auto-created stats for the table in your results set? What value is `swType`? You can view the object stats in [`sys.stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx).

Comment: Indeed when swType is SQL_TABLE_STAT I have no information for index or column. 

For the good scenario I observed that my while loop had 3 iterations including one of having swType = SQL_TABLE_STAT without information in szIdxName. But for the bad scenario the loop had only 2 iteration. So it looks like SQLExtendedFetch() is not stepping for one index. Remus, related to your questions, I didn't dived such deep. Please, can you be more specific of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the workaround: using a query through **sys.tables** and **sys.indexes** tables.

Comment: You can find more details about this approach into my [article](http://silviuardelean.ro/2014/04/07/getting-tables-indexes-experiences-workaround/).